# Split string by whitespace and select second part SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have written a query which returns a table with one column and one row.

Example:

```
+---------------+
| playerID      | 
+---------------+
| Adam Overflow |            
+---------------+
```

**Desired Result** I want to select the second part of that name from that table so the output is **Overflow**.

I have tried to figure out the STRING_SPLIT function, but I cannot seem to get it to work.
This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(
SELECT playerID FROM Players, ' ');
```

And the Players table is as described. The error I get is:

> Syntax error in FROM clause

I realize this should be relatively simple and there might be a duplicate answer on here, but again I cannot seem to figure it out.
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What if there's no space or multiple spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string_split()` is not the right tool for this job; it is a set-returning functions (it create rows), and does not guarantee ordering whatsoever.

You can just use scalar string functions:

```
select 
    playerID, 
    substring(playerID, charindex(' ', playerID) + 1, len(playerID)) as shortID
from players
```

`right()` also comes to mind:

```
right(playerID, len(playerID) - charindex(' ', playerID)) as shortID
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f5cee1fc1c756950b8bac8291b4d4ab)**:

```
select 
    playerID, 
    substring(playerID, charindex(' ', playerID) + 1, len(playerID)) shortID1,
    right(playerID, len(playerID) - charindex(' ', playerID)) shortID2
from (values ('Adam Overflow')) as t(playerID)
GO
```

```
playerID      | shortID1 | shortID2
:------------ | :------- | :-------
Adam Overflow | Overflow | Overflow
```

Comment: Do you know why charindex wouldn't work on W3 Schools? I seem to get this error: Undefined function 'CHARINDEX' in expression.

I see your example on DB Fiddle, but it does not seem to work on W3 which is where I am trying this.

Comment: @ghDev It works just fine. Try `SELECT right('Adam Overflow', len('Adam Overflow') - charindex(' ', 'Adam Overflow')) AS MatchPosition;`

Answer (score 0):

This should bring the required result:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( a.TheData , LEN(a.TheData ) -  CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(a.TheData )) + 2  , LEN(a.TheData )  ) results FROM (select 'playerID' as TheData
union all
select 'Adam Overflow'
union all
select 'Adam Overflow Meta') a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using `string_split()`:

```
SELECT value
FROM players p CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT(p.playerID, ' ') s
WHERE p.playerID LIKE ' ' + s.value + '%';
```